# Immutablejs - Update Values in nested Map and List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have this immutableJs map:

```
event: {
    days: [
        {
            date: 1,
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 2,
                    startTime: 1,
                    endTime: 1,
                    description: 1,
                    detailsLink: 1,
                    details: {visible: true}
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 2,
                    startTime: 2,
                    endTime: 2,
                    description: 2,
                    detailsLink: 2,
                    details: {visible: false}
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 3,
                    startTime: 3,
                    endTime: 3,
                    description: 3,
                    detailsLink: 3,
                    details: {visible: true}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            date: 2,
            sessions: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 2,
                    startTime: 1,
                    endTime: 1,
                    description: 1,
                    detailsLink: 1,
                    details: {visible: false}
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 2,
                    startTime: 2,
                    endTime: 2,
                    description: 2,
                    detailsLink: 2,
                    details: {visible: false}
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 3,
                    startTime: 3,
                    endTime: 3,
                    description: 3,
                    detailsLink: 3,
                    details: {visible: true}
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the ones that are visible: true to visible:false. I tried a lot of different ways with filter, seq, etc. But no luck.

Any ideas of how I could do this with immutableJs?

Answer (score 0):

Late comer to the party, but how about this (assuming your data is in a variable called `data`) :

```
data.setIn(["event", "days"],
    data.getIn(["event", "days"]).map(day => 
        day.set("sessions", day.get("sessions").map(session => 
            session.setIn(['details', 'visible'], false)))
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

In ES6, which probably can be easily translated into immutableJS....

```js
const notVisibleEvents = {
    ...events,
    days: events.days.map(d => {
        return {
            ...d,
            sessions: d.sessions.map(s => {
                return {
                    ...s,
                    details: {
                        ...s.details,
                        visible: false
                    }
                };
            })
        };
    })
};
```